# Efficient alternative to subqueries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, subquery, query-performance

Take the following two mock tables:

> dbo.animal

```
id  name
1   dog
2   cat
```

> dbo.animal_food

```
id  animal_id  food_id  active
1   1          4        1
2   1          5        1
```

I need to query against `animal` with multiple subqueries of `animal_food` based on different sorted results. Something like this:

```
 select name, 
        (   select top 1 food_id 
              from animal_food 
             where animal_id = animal.id 
             order by food_id desc) as max_food_id,
        (   select top 1 food_id 
              from animal_food 
             where animal_id = animal.id 
               and active = 1
             order by food_id desc) as max_active_food_id,
  from animal
```

This is obviously very inefficient---I need to speed it up. However, I can't figure out how to refactor this into a join that would improve performance.

Comment: For questions about performance of queries it is a good idea to include an actual execution plan. You are saying *"obviously very inefficient"* but the query optimizer might cook something up that *is* efficient (or efficient enough at least).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the two food_id values you specified, you can use `join` with `group by` and what's called *conditional aggregation*, like this:

```
select 
    name, 
    max(animal_food.food_id) as max_food_id,
    max(case when animal_food.active = 1 then animal_food.food_id else null end) as max_active_food_id,
from animal
inner join animal_food on animal.animal_id = animal_food.animal_id
group by animal.animal_id, animal.name
```

Comment: This slowed the query down :(

Comment: Did you check the explain plan for both queries???? That's the only real way to know for sure.  If for your original query is faster than this one, perhaps your premise of "this is obviously very inefficient" should be proven out...

Comment: I was under the impression that subqueries were slower in general. I guess I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a simple aggregate query, with the only twist being that the third column only considers the max `food_id` where `active = 1`. If that's the case, this will do the job without subqueries:

```
SELECT
  name,
  MAX(food_id) AS max_food_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN active = 1 THEN food_id END) AS max_active_food_id
FROM animal
JOIN animal_food = animal.id = animal_food.id
GROUP BY name
```

The `MAX(CASE WHEN active = 1 THEN food_id END)` will return `NULL` if `active` doesn't equal 1, and nulls are ignored for aggregates like `MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use cross apply function and check which way performs better

```
 select name, 
        max_food_id.food_id AS max_food_id,
        max_active_food_id.food_id AS max_active_food_id,
  from animal
  cross apply (
   select top 1 food_id 
              from animal_food 
             where animal_id = animal.id 
             order by food_id desc
) AS max_food_id
cross apply
(   select top 1 food_id 
              from animal_food 
             where animal_id = animal.id 
               and active = 1
             order by food_id desc) as max_active_food_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about performance but here is the query using joins and aggregates. Is this what you are looking for or have you already tried this?

```
select animal.name
    , max(animal_food_all.food_id) as max_food_id
    , max(animal_food_active.food_id) as max_active_food_id
from animal
    left outer join animal_food as animal_food_all on animal.id = animal_food_all.animal_id
    left outer join animal_food as animal_food_active on animal.id = animal_food_active.animal_id and animal_food_active.active = 1
GROUP BY animal.name
```

I used outer joins in case there are animals that do not have a food listed, if you want those omitted you can change it inner join but either way it will probably have little (if any) impact on performance.

Comment: wouldn't a single scan of animal_food be preferable?

Comment: @SlimsGhost - It might depend on the data and existing indexes but you are probably right. The best thing to do is to take your answer and mine and what the OP has and bench mark them in SSMS as well as compare execution plans.